# I have the identifiers for my wallet, but I don't know how to access it

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery

I am a cryptocurrency novice, so I apologize in advance if this question is too basic. About a year or so ago I created 2 bitcoin wallets and put a small amount of money in them. I forgot about them until recently when I found the sheet of paper where I wrote down the identifiers for them.

In addition, there is a long list of random words associated with each wallet. My question is, I know this should be enough information to access my wallet, but I don't know what to do with the information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your list of words is 12, 18, or 24 words long, it is likely a BIP 39 seed. This means that you should be able to access your Bitcoin by using any software that supports BIP 39 seeds (such as Electrum) and restoring your wallet from those words. Note that not all wallets that support BIP 39 will derive addresses in the same way; some derive them with a different derivation path so you may not necessarily see your Bitcoin and may have to use a different wallet. For most wallets though, it should work.

The exception is MultiBit HD. If you think you used MultiBit HD, you can only use MultiBit HD to restore the wallet. MultiBit HD will not be able to restore your Bitcoin if you a different wallet generated the seed (well technically it will restore, you just won't see any balance).